# How do I force-indicate a vocabulary as a source for node breadcrumbs?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have two vocabularies on my site, each node of certain content type has 2 term reference fields - one per vocabulary, single value only. For browsing through both vocabularies I am using Taxonomy Menu and Taxonomy Breadcrumb modules.

As long as I'm browsing through terms, the breadcrumb is ok, the problem starts when I step down to a node instance - the breadcrumb path is then always taken from vocabulary A, while what I want is the path from vocabulary B.

In the content type definition I checked vocabulary A as the source of active trail for menu (this is Taxonomy Menu setting most probably). Apparently that does not influence the breadcrumb. However, none of the options in the Taxonomy Breadcrumb config screen seems to have any impact on the source of the breadcrumbs.

What else should I check?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Crumbs](http://drupal.org/project/crumbs) instead of taxonomy breadcrumb.
You can be bold and try the 7.x-2.x branch (*)

Documentation for Crumbs + Taxonomy: http://drupal.org/node/1984484

I have not personally tried it in combination with taxonomy menu, but think it should work ok.

To solve the problem on node pages:

- Install Crumbs
- Visit Admin > Structure > Crumbs to adjust the plugin priorities (*).
- The `taxonomy.termReference.field_vocab_B.node.certain_node_type` (**) needs to be moved up, into the "Enabled" section.

You can do more stuff with Crumbs (you could even replace taxonomy menu with menupoly), but one question at a time.

(*) The crumbs-7.x-2.x, among other things, has a revamped admin UI to set the plugin priorities. It is still not perfect, which is the main reason there is no 7.x-2.0 stable yet.

(**) Thanks to the wildcard system, you could also move `taxonomy.termReference.field_vocab_B.node.*` or even `taxonomy.termReference.field_vocab_B.*` into "Enabled", instead of `taxonomy.termReference.field_vocab_B.node.certain_node_type`. Doing that would activate this behavior for other node types and/or other entity types that have field_vocab_B.